# New library usage issues - JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created a 'component library' that I am trying to use in another project, but I am facing a lot of issues getting it to work.

I initially thought it was due to how my files were being built into the `/dist` folder by the `tsc` command, but I have since changed my `tsconfig` to match a similar library of mine that **does** work, but I'm still getting the same issues.

Both of these repos are held in npm privately.

I am importing my components as `import Container from '@company_name/My-Library'` and using with `<Component ... />`, however my IDE shows red squigglies under my usage with the message:

> JSX element type 'Container' does not have any construct or call signatures.

I of course get the same error for the other components when used in this way.
And when running the local server instance, I get errors:

> export 'default' (imported as 'Container') was not found in '@company_name/My-Library' (module has no exports)

File structure:

```
.
└── My-Library/
    ├── dist/
    │   ├── container/
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── header/
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── index.d.ts
    │   └── index.js
    └── src/
        ├── container/
        │   ├── index.ts
        │   ├── container.tsx
        │   ├── container-footer.tsx
        │   └── ...
        ├── header/
        │   ├── index.ts
        │   ├── header.tsx
        │   ├── mobile-header.tsx
        │   └── standard-header.tsx
        └── index.ts
```

**src/index.ts**

```
export * from './container';
export * from './header';
...
```

Similarly the sub-dir `index.ts` files export the main components such as `header/container.tsx`.

The components themselves are ES6 with `default` exports like:

```
const Container = (props) => {
    // Component code here
}

export default Container;
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDirs": [
      "src"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true, // I have this so I don't have to include React import
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Doing such gets me the following in my `dist`:
**index.js**

```
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(m, k);
    if (!desc || ("get" in desc ? !m.__esModule : desc.writable || desc.configurable)) {
      desc = { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } };
    }
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, desc);
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __exportStar = (this && this.__exportStar) || function(m, exports) {
    for (var p in m) if (p !== "default" && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(exports, p)) __createBinding(exports, m, p);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__exportStar(require("./container"), exports);
__exportStar(require("./header"), exports);
// More exports
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```